# Angular How to Fetch or select data from array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have two data collection 1 which contains the header data or the column to be displayed.

Another is the actual data source.

Now what I have to do from that JSON data I have to select only that data which are in that header list.

Below is the sample of the data

Header Data Array : `["Execution_Plan_Note", "Budget", "Reporting_Period", "Budget_Note", "Spend_Plan_Note", "Spend_Plan"]`

And Actual Data Source

[image]

So from the below collection, I want only data that are in the header data array in the new object
how I can achieve this if any 1 has an idea let me know i have tried almost everything.

Comment: "i have tried almost everything" Please include those attempts in your question so that we don't recommend them to you again.  Include as much debugging detail and attempts as would help to provide an [mre].

Comment: just need an idea of how i can filter data from JSON array base on my header data or header keys.

Comment: simplest one would be `list.map(({key1, key2}) => ({key1, key2}))`

Comment: You can certainly achieve it with some `reduce` and `map` , or look at `lodash.pick` https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.pick

Comment: @Ravikumar i will  try your way and let you know

Comment: if you have dynamic keys, like @dbuchet suggested you can use  `_.map(list, item => _.pick(item, keysArray))` using lodash.

Comment: okey  i will try i dont want to use any extra library is there any other naive way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `map` and `reduce` like below.

```js
const keysArray = ['a', 'b'];
const list = [{a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c'}, {a: 'a1', b: 'b1', c: 'c1'}, {a: 'a2', b: 'b2', c: 'c2'}];

const result = list.map(item => keysArray.reduce((acc, key) => {
 acc[key] = item[key];
return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```